# How to deactivate a user without deleting him in parse.com?

Tags: authentication, parse-platform, user-controls

I want to deactivate a user in parse.com, so when he tries to connect, he will be informed that his accounts is deactivated.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Add your attempt(s) here and specify what your problem is in your code

Comment: i can make the user authenticate but i really don't know how to proceed and modify the user class and how to check in the authentication. i'm new to parse so i'm reading the docs with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to Parse, but could you add a bool column in your class that is called active.  Then you can check that column to see if it is true.  If false show your alert stating they are inactive.

Comment: Or a string column called 'state' would work even better, so that you can assign multiple states and wont be limited by just the two.

Comment: i'm new too to Parse and i really don't know how to do this, i downloaded Parse sdk and it work perfectly, the problem is how to add this kind of stuff and how to check this with it.

Comment: @AhmedCommando I'm sure there should be samples and a stack of documentation because it is an SDK. SO is not here to teach you how to use a specific technology etc. It is up to you to try things, and if you are stuck and don't know why because everything seems logical and correct to you, you can ask for help. Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/help items regarding asking questions. You must have at least a basic understanding what you are trying to accomplish before you ask a question, and you need to attempt something in the process